# Insert and Select Data in Redis

Tags: redis, nosql

I need to enter the below data in Redis:

```
Atlanta_96_Bronze Ana_Moser Ida_Alvares Ana_Paula Hilma_Caldeira Leila_Barros Virna_Dias Marcia_Fu Ericleia_Bodziak Ana_Flavia_Sanglard Fernanda_Venturini Fofao_Helia_Souza Sandra_Suruagy

Sidney_00_Bronze Elisangela_Oliveira Erika_Coimbra Fofao_Helia_Souza Janina_Conceicao Karin_Rodrigues Katia_Lopes Kely_Fraga Leila_Barros Raquel_Silva Ricarda_Lima Virna_Dias Walewska_Oliveira

Pequim_08_Gold Marianne_Steinbrecher Fofao_Helia_Souza Paula_Pequeno Walewska_Oliveira Thaisa_Menezes Valeska_Menezes Welissa_Gonzaga Fabiana_Oliveira Fabiana_Claudino Sheilla_Castro Jaqueline_Carvalho Carolina_Albuquerque

Londres_12_Gold Fabiana_Claudino Dani_Lins Paula_Pequeno Adenizia_Silva Thaisa_Menezes Jaqueline_Carvalho Fernanda_Ferreira Tandara_Caixeta Natalia_Pereira Sheilla_Castro Fabiana_Oliveira Fernanda_Garay
```

And then perform the following queries:

- Which players won gold and silver medals?
- Which players won two gold medals?
- Which players only won medal in '96?
- Which players were in the 96, 00 and 08 Olympics?
- Which players were only in the 12 olympics?

But I never touched Redis, I came from a relational world, I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Redis doesn't really seem like the right tool for the job as you've described it, as Redis is more of a cache than a database. There's no concept of running a "query" in Redis.

If you must use Redis, I would recommend storing the data in multiple sets to facilitate getting to the answers you need.

You might make a set for each type of medal, for example (a set of gold medalists, a set of silver medalists, and a set of bronze medalists). Then you could ask for the union of the gold and silver sets (Redis's SUNION operator) to get the answer to your first question.

You might also make a set for each year, so that you could retrieve information by year (for your last three questions).

In some cases, there may be no way around doing some coding to refine the results to give you exactly the answers you need.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification. It's a college paper, it needs to be delivered in Redis.